# Splitting string into an array results in an empty array

Tags: perl

For this script users can input what projects they want used as a command line argument (`$opt_proj`) in a csv format like this: `Proj1,Proj2,Proj3`

I want to split these up to get each individually, but I'm not sure why the `split` command won't populate my array with the projects.

Code:

```
my @projects;
if ( defined $opt_proj ) {
    print $opt_proj;
    my @projects=split /,/,$opt_proj;
}   
print "@projects\n";
exit;
```

`$opt_proj` contains the data and prints out `Proj1,Proj2,Proj3`.
But, `@projects` appears to be empty. I have also tried printing the contents of `@projects` with a `foreach` loop and same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is [scope](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro#Variable-scoping).  Just remove the `my` keyword inside the `if` block:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $opt_proj = 'Proj1,Proj2,Proj3';
my @projects;
if ( defined $opt_proj ) {
    print $opt_proj, "\n";
    @projects=split /,/,$opt_proj;
}   
print "@projects\n";
exit;
```

This prints:

```
Proj1,Proj2,Proj3
Proj1 Proj2 Proj3
```

Your code creates a new variable `@projects` inside the `if` block which can not be seen outside the block.